# nodejs gridfs buffer is offset by two bytes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I'm using this function to retrieve the file. there are some other function calls before that pulls the md5sum out of the request, makes sure the file exists, then calls buildFile().

```
 FileChunker.prototype.buildFile = function(file, callback) {
         self = this;
         console.log(file);

         this.gridfs.get(file._id, function(error, data) {
                 if (error) {
                         console.log(error);
                         callback(error);
                 }
                 else {
                         callback(null, data);
                 }       
         });     
    };
```

here's the resulting hexdumps.

original file on disk (imported via mongofiles, can be properly retrieved via mongofiles)

```
~/_nodejs% hexdump -C test.txt
00000000  41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48  49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f 50  |ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP|
00000010  0a                                                |.|
00000011
```

output from nodejs

```
~/_nodejs% hexdump -C OUTPUT
00000000  11 00 00 00 41 42 43 44  45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c  |....ABCDEFGHIJKL|
00000010  4d                                                |M|
00000011
```

if we `console.log` the Buffer object, we see the extra data as well:

```
 <Buffer 11 00 00 00 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d>
```

I've been smashing my head against this for some time and have no idea what to do next. it's like the `gridfs.get()` is just returning the wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

can you post an issue on the git repo, please provide node version, mongodb version, driver version and steps to reproduce it (preferably code). Otherwise I'm a bit blind here.